# Bootstrap multi column dropdown without custom css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to create bootstrap multilevel menu with multi column sub menu. I can do this by adding custom style for drop-down. But I would like to know if there are default bootstrap classes for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do using bootstrap (.row) class with column

here is link for multicolumn bootstrap dropdown
http://alijafarian.com/demos/bootstrap-multi-column-dropdown-menu/

Comment: That is looking good. But there is some custom style .`dropdown-menu.columns-2 { min-width: 400px;}` I want bootstrap default class.